# Exported Text File Invisible?

Tags: android, file-io

I have an android app where I am writing data (csv format) to the filesystem for export.

The app writes the file without any problem (I can see it in the file manager app). The issue is when I plug my device into my PC, the file doesn't show up?

I am writing to the downloads directory using this code to get the file path:

```
public File getDataStorageDir() {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
    File base = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    base = new File(base, "F3F");
    base.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(base.getAbsolutePath() + String.format("/%s.txt", mRace.name));

    return file;
}
```

I can export the file to dropbox or email it, but I would also like to be able to plug in via usb and drag it off the filesystem. Could this be something to do with permissions?

Thanks

Comment: @Funkystein - the usb connection is fine. I can see other files. I have also found that If I rename the file in file manager on the device it then shows up?

Comment: I have similar trouble. I think android OS is not correct. Because this was after copy by any 'file explorer' any file from one folder on sdcard to another folder in sdcard when phone is linked to PC. When I copied file I can't see him in second folder via PC. And I can see second file after reboot phone and PC and relink.

Comment: @Funkystein - I tried adding flush() before calling close(), but no difference - still not showing, but as soon as I rename it - it appears.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the file name contains not allowerd chars for Windows (`/`, `*`, `:`, ...). Which are legal on Unix, Linux and Android (which is Linux based).

Comment: The test case I am using is called hoh.txt - I rename it to hoh2.txt, and it appears. I think @Tapa Save is correct - it's a bug in Android. I am testing on ICS (4.0.3), so maybe it is fixed in later releases?

Comment: I have similar on 4.3 (Sony device with internal 'ext_card' and external 'sdcard'). Reboot PC and android device and you can see hoh2.txt

Comment: Ok - well thanks for your help guys, I guess we will just have to live with it!

Comment: Have you tried setting the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission? Like so: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` inside the manifest tag.

Comment: Yes - there is no problem writing the file. It just does't show up on a PC when I try to access the disk through a usb connection.

Comment: It's a bug of Android: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/not-all-files-are-visible-over-mtp